# Implementing resource_owner_authenticator doesnt work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

I'm writing an API aside with an web page. I want to have Oauth2 login so i can keep a session from the mobile device, i've already install the GEM doorkeeper and run the migration how it's explained on [this site.](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper)

where i'm getting stuck is in the resource_owner_from_credentials  parts, since i have an User model which has authenticate method given by the has_secure_password helper from rails. this is how my /config/initializers/doorkeeper.rb file looks like

```
Doorkeeper.configure do
  # Change the ORM that doorkeeper will use.
  # Currently supported options are :active_record, :mongoid2, :mongoid3, :mongo_mapper
  orm :active_record

  # This block will be called to check whether the resource owner is authenticated or not.
  resource_owner_from_credentials do
    User.find_by_email(params[:email]).authenticate(params[:password])
  end
##lots of comments
end
```

and when go to

```
localhost:3000/oauth/authorize
```

i get this:

```
config/initializers/doorkeeper.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

then i tried:

```
 http://127.0.0.1:3000/oauth/authorize?email=puca@gmail.com&password=porche
```

and the same

what i'm i doing wrong? how should i configuresource_owner_authenticator block? how do i get the token?

Answer (score 1):

As per [this doorkeeper wiki page](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Using-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-flow) you need to send a POST request to `/oauth/token` API with the following params:

```
{
  "grant_type"    : "password",
  "username"      : "user@example.com",
  "password"      : "sekret"
}
```

When this request is processed, doorkeeper calls the `resource_owner_from_credentials` block and passes the params to it. So you have access to the param named `username` and not `email`.

To summarize, fix the API endpoint to `/oauth/token` , change `params[:email]` to `params[:username]` and everything should work.